# Variant Type Mismatch in VB6

Tags: vb6, variant

I'm trying to code up a call to a method whose second parameter appears to be a variant (so far as I can tell from the object browser, anyway).

It is customary in the application I am working on to call it like this:-

```
Call StrangeMethod ("Fred", Array (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

But when I try to call it like this:-

```
Dim myArray as Variant
myArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
Call StrangeMethod("Fred", myArray)
```

the call fails with a `Type Mismatch` error. What am I doing wrong here and how do I correct it?

**Edit**
As requested in the comments, the method signature in the object browser is:-

```
Strangemethod(Path As String, Commands)
```

Comment: Could not repro. When I setup the second parm as Variant, both calls work fine.  Could you edit the question to include the method signature from the Object Browser?

Comment: Can you try `Dim myArray() As Variant`

Comment: This is a bug in the C/C++ impl. of `IDispatch::Invoke` method of the class you are using (does not like `VT_BYREF` flag). Same problem the `MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest` has with `Send` method. Try using `Call StrangeMethod("Fred", CVar(myArray))` to strip `VT_BYREF` flag.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I have edited the question as you suggested, but either of the other suggestions fix the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel that fixes the problem, thank you.

Comment: @wqw that also fixes the problem, thank you; I've used Justin's method though.